# C doesn't print the strings

Tags: c++, c

This program exits with The program '[6576] ICP2-TaskA.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

I tried to add some code after scanf but the program exited before executing those.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name[40];
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("name is: %s", name);

    getchar();
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Use printf("name is: %s\n", name);

Comment: Your program is likely printing the string once it is terminated because the output is line-buffered, but you are probably using some kind of IDE which is closing the window at that time. The solution provided by @VladfromMoscow will flush the output buffer once the newline encountered.

Comment: Or an explicit flush after the `printf`: `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: There should be a whole bunch of duplicates. Perhaps someone have in their bookmarks...

Comment: I tried to add some other codes after it, but it got exit after the scanf

Comment: it seems to work ok in msvc 2019

Comment: Buffer overflow?  `scanf("%39s", name)`, and check its return value.  If `scanf()` couldn't read from stdin, the content of `name` is uninitialised.

Comment: The scanf asks to be scanf_s, if i put scanf_s this error shows: Exception thrown at 0x68B20B5C (ucrtbased.dll) in ConsoleApplication6.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x01100000.

Comment: @AdnanMuhammad please show the actual code you attempted to use `scanf_s()` in.

Comment: There was no any issue with the code, I just had to add getchar() and getchar() at the end of the code and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

you may have to flush the output buffer

```
printf("name is: %s\n", name);
```

or

```
fflush(stdout)
```